# jdbc to access complete database

Tags: java, ms-access

i want what should be given in DriverManager.getConnection() when i want to access all tables from ms-access

Comment: Can you clarify what is you problem/question?

Comment: in case when we want to acess a single table we would specify its name along with driver but what should be done to acess all tables??

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`DriverManager.getConnection(String url, Properties info)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Properties%29). What problem doesn't this solve?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to connect to an MS Access DB without creating a DSN.

In any case this works fine with acess everytime.

DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:/data/data.MDB","","");

Change the DBQ argument to your MDB file.

Comment: what does DBQ=C:/data/data.MDB","",""); mean

Comment: This is not a separate Java statement. This goes as part of the connection string. The first argument to the getConnection method.